# Regex not working in PHP code but working fine in the sandbox

Tags: php, regex

I faced a strange situation. I'd like to get ZIP code from address and my regex

```
\b(\w+)\b[^\w]\p{L}+$
```

works in sandbox
https://regex101.com/r/rnjecA/1
but with the same text it's not working in PHP
https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/3eb95
What's the matter is here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
$str = <<<AAA
County Road 99
Sauk Centre,  Minnesota 56378
USA
AAA;

if (preg_match('~(\w+)\R\p{L}+$~u', $str, $m)) {
  print_r($m);
}
// => Array( [0] => 56378\nUSA  [1] => 56378 )
```

See [the PHP online demo](https://3v4l.org/ebOeW).

If you do not need the whole match and just need the ZIP as output, replace the pattern with

```
'~\w+(?=\R\p{L}+$)~u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rnjecA/2).

**Note**:

- `(\w+)\R\p{L}+$` - matches and captures into Group 1 any Unicode word chars (due to `u` flag), then `\R` matches ***any Unicode line break sequence***, and then `\p{L}+` matches one or more Unicode letters (till the end of string (`$`)
- `\R` solves the problem with matching LF or CRLF line endings
- When using Unicode property classes and dealing with Unicode strings, remember to use `u` flag with PHP PCRE/PCRE2 regexps.